# WPF Textbox is collapsed when the content string is a single digit

Tags: wpf

I am working on an application that creates textboxes/combo boxes dynamically based on if there is a single replacement for a keyword, or multiple replacements, and adds them to a stackpanel. I have ran into an issue where if the string that is being populated into the textbox is a single digit, ie: "2" the textbox is collapsed. Here is the associated DependencyProperty and constructor for the view model:

```
    #region Properties
    public ObservableCollection<string> KeywordValueList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(_KeywordValueListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(_KeywordValueListProperty, value); }
    }
    private static readonly DependencyProperty _KeywordValueListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeywordValueList",
                                                                                              typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
                                                                                              typeof(KeywordControlViewModel),
                                                                                              new PropertyMetadata(null, null));
    public string KeywordValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(_KeywordValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(_KeywordValueProperty, value); }
    }    
    private static readonly DependencyProperty _KeywordValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeywordValue",
                                                                                              typeof(string),
                                                                                              typeof(KeywordControlViewModel),
                                                                                              new PropertyMetadata(null, null));
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public KeywordControlViewModel(string keyword, object keywordValue)
    {
        Keyword = keyword;
        if (keywordValue is string)
        {
            KeywordValue = (string)keywordValue;
            KeywordValueList = null;
        }
        else if (keywordValue is ICollection)
        {
            KeywordValue = null;
            ObservableCollection<string> toSet = new ObservableCollection<string>(keywordValue as List<string>);
            KeywordValueList = toSet;
        }
        else
        {
            KeywordValue = "-Not Set-";
            KeywordValueList = null;
        }            
    }
    #endregion
```

This is the relevant portion of the xaml:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/ControlsStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-- Labels etc on Row 0, generating properly so omitting for space-->
<TextBox  Name ="KeyWordTextBox"
              Style="{StaticResource InputBoxStyle}" 
              Text="{Binding KeywordValue}"
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Visibility="{Binding KeywordValue, TargetNullValue=Hidden}">
        <TextBox.ToolTip>
            <Label Content="{Binding Keyword, StringFormat='Edit value for {0}'}" />
        </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
<ComboBox Name="KeyWordComboBox"
              ItemsSource="{Binding KeywordValueList}"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding KeywordValueList, TargetNullValue=Hidden}"/>
</Grid>
```

And the style:

```
<Style x:Key="InputBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
</Style>
```

I have debugged quite a bit and found that if I change the single digit to either a single letter, string of more than one number, or string containing both it shows the textbox as expected. Also, the Visibility value for the textbox in the debugger shows Collapsed, not Hidden -- the TargetNullValue does not seem to be causing this. In fact the textbox does not show either if I change it to Visible. This only started happening when I added the option for a combobox, prior to that the textbox generated properly with a single digit.

Can anyone offer an idea why this may be happening?

Comment: You probably have it in a `Grid.Column` that has its `Width` set to `"Auto"` instead of `"*"`.

Comment: Your problem is *not* demonstrated by this code. Please edit your question to show code that *does*.

Comment: Added more of the code, does this better demonstrate what I'm talking about? What else would you need to see if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the code doesn't work because You are binding a `string` value (and `ObservableCollection<string>` value in case of combobox) to a `Visibility` property.

In order to hide controls on `null` value:

- You can write a value converter similar to the one suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123905/232530 (but just check if `value` parameter is `null` in the `Convert` method)

or

- You can use triggers as suggested here: [How to hide the empty TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573864/how-to-hide-the-empty-textblock).

Please let me know if You need help when using any of those solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I added the converter and changed it to work with both the strings and ICollection and it works perfectly.I wonder if it was going collapsed due to the value '2' meaning collapsed behind the scenes. Out of interest I tried to assign the visibility to 2 and see if it got the same effect, but it didn't compile.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :). I'm curious why it worked this way as well. It seems that in the `Visibility` enumeration, `Collapsed` is associated with value `2`, so maybe this allowed it to be interpreted this way. Probably later I'll write some quick sample and try to check how it woks. If I find anything interesting, I'll write information about it here :).