# Binding default value to visibility if default value is null in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, ivalueconverter

The first time loading a window I want a textbox to be collapsed while keeping a binding to a property (SomeProp) in my Viewmodel.

Unfortunatly I am not able to do this.

what I have tried:

Attempt 1:
I have tried to explicity set the value to null in the constructor of the viewmodel and also explicitely call the Onpropertychanged. The Convertor is not triggered.

Attempt 2:
In the code behind I've set the default visibility to visibility.Collapsed. this seems to have a side-effect that the Visibility is no longer bound to the SomeProp property.

Attempt 3:
After googling I found something about PriorityBinding, but this seems to only work on the TEXT property of the textbox
[Use a default value when binding cannot be evaluated because of a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259315/use-a-default-value-when-binding-cannot-be-evaluated-because-of-a-null-value)

Thank you in advance,

Extra Info:

I have a textbox and it should only be visible if a property (SomeProp) in my ViewModel has a value 'Other'.
I am successfully using a Convertor for this. This means whenever I change the value of SomeProp the textbox becomes visible/invisible depending on the value of SomeProp.
I have used the following code: 
[WPF: Binding Visibility by string contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122780/wpf-binding-visibility-by-string-contents)

Does anyone know how I can set te textbox Visibility to Collapsed while keeping the Binding to a property SomeProp.

XAML

```
        <TextBox Name="txtbox" Visibility="{Binding SomeProp.Description, Converter={StaticResource StringOtherToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="150" MaxLength="2000"
                 Text="{Binding SomeProp2.Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True">
        </TextBox>
```

Convertor

```
class StringOtherToVisibilityConverter : System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

    if (value != null)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "Other")
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

}
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return null; //DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}

public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return this;
}


}
```

Comment: Setting `TargetNullValue={x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}` should collapse the binding target when the source value is null.  You can also set `FallbackValue`, which is applied when the binding or conversion fails.

Comment: TargetNullValue does not work. Maybe because I'm using SomeProp.Description while SomeProp is null ?

FallBackValue on the other hand does work. Thanks. If you answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `TargetNullValue={x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}` should collapse the binding target when the source value is `null`.

You can also set `FallbackValue`, which is applied when the binding or conversion fails.  Such failures may include the `NullReferenceException` that would occur when binding to `X.Y` if `X` is `null`.